# Keep the value of TextFromField between pages

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, textfield

As an exercise I'm trying to duplicate an app with flutter, but I'm having a problem with a TextFromField.
Basically I should be able to write a text in the TextFromField, than choose the color (and other stuff..). To choose the color I will open a ShowDialog, select the color and than go back to the previous page. The problem is that when I go back to the page I lost the value of the TextFromField because basically I'm reloading the page.

I need to achive this:
[image]

As you can see on the original app, when I choose the color the text 'TEST' is still there! I'm new to Flutter and I really don't know how to do that :( Help.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextFormField` won't remember the value for you, you have to remember the value and give it to `TextFormField`'s controller. You need to plan a [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) approach to make this happen. There can be multiple ways to make this happen. Posting your code can be helpful to get actual suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Store the VALUE you get in your textController for that TextFormField in a Key-Value store.

Before starting, add the shared_preferences plugin to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
content_copy
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "<newest version>"
```

and then store like in the example below

```
// obtain shared preferences
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// set value
prefs.setInt(txtFmFld, VALUE);
```

It will be persistent across pages